# Want a specific color only on two pages

Tags: php, html, css

I want two links to have specific colors.
when on the homepage or the about-page i want it to be white.
when im on the contact page, i want it to be black

```
    <li><a <?php if($page == 'Home' or 'Over mij'){echo'style="color:white"';} ?> href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a <?php if($page == 'Home' || 'Over mij'){echo'style="color:white"';} ?> href="index.php">Home</a></li>
```

I tried either of the options above, but it wont help. it only changes the color on the homepage but not the about page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li>
    <a <?php if($page == 'Home' || $page == 'Over mij')
                {echo 'style="color:white;"';} 
             else if($page == 'Contacts') 
                {echo 'style="color:black;"';} 
        ?> href="index.php">Home</a></li>
```